# Assigning d3.csv response to a global variable

Tags: javascript, d3.js, global-variables

I want to assign the data that is loaded from a csv file using d3.csv(), to a global variable, so I can use it later on in my code, but I am get undefined for the global variable dataset.

```
var dataset;

d3.csv("/csv/census_tracts.csv", function(data){
   dataset=data;
   });

console.log(dataset);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is problem of Asynchronous, try with `setTime`

for instance:

```js
var dataset;

d3.csv("/csv/census_tracts.csv", function(data){
   dataset=data;
   });
setTimeout(function(){
console.log(dataset);
},200);
```